# How to get Rcpp to work?

Tags: r, gcc, rcpp

I cannot get Rcpp to work on Windows 8.1. When I run the following minimal example, I get an error.

```
> library(Rcpp)
> evalCpp("1 + 1")
g++ -m64 -I"C:/R/R-31~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/R/R-3.1.0/library/Rcpp/include"  -  
I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c file11dc2120723d.cpp -o  
file11dc2120723d.o g++: not found make: *** [file11dc2120723d.o] Error 127 Warning message: running
command 'make -f "C:/R/R-31~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/R/R-31~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk"
SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="sourceCpp_97232.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64
OBJECTS="file11dc2120723d.o"' had status 2  
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, showOutput = showOutput,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

The two first entries in my path are:
    PATH=c:\Rtools\bin;c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;

R is installed in a directory C:\R\R-3.1.0

Rtools is in the directory C:\R\Rtools

Some additional information:

```
> library(devtools)
> find_rtools(T)

Scanning path...
ls : c:\Rtools\bin\ls.exe 
Scanning registry...
Found c:/Rtools for 3.1 
VERSION.txt
Rtools version 3.1.0.1942 
 [1] TRUE

> has_devel()
"C:/R/R-31~1.0/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD SHLIB foo.c 

gcc -m64 -I"C:/R/R-31~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     
O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c foo.c -o foo.o
gcc: not found
make: *** [foo.o] Error 127
Warning message:
running command 'make -f "C:/R/R-31~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/R/R-31~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk"
SHLIB="foo.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="foo.o"' had status 2 
Error: Command failed (1)

> system('g++ -v')
Warning message:
running command 'g++ -v' had status 127
```

Comment: Something is not right with your path. Re-read the manuals and try again.  You need to restart the cmd.exe prompt, and/or R/RStudio to have changes take effect.

Comment: What does `system( "SET PATH" )` gives you ?

Comment: `system("SET PATH")` gives me
`Warning message:
running command 'SET PATH' had status 127`

Comment: my full PATH is: ` c:\Rtools\bin;c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Python27\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ `

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if you have solved your problem but it appears you don't have gcc or g++ installed.  For windows you can get these tools with MinGW.

1. Install MinGW which you can donwload from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/).  The homepage for information is [here](http://www.mingw.org/)
2. Once you have it installed MinGW, you can open the 'MinGW Installation Manager' and install the bin and dev for 'mingw32-gcc-g++'.
3. You must then update your PATH environmental variable to include 'C:\MinGW\bin' and 'C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin'.
4. Restart your R session, couldn't hurt to also reinstall 'Rcpp', and try`require(Rcpp); evalCpp("1 + 1")` again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while trying to call C-code directly. Switching from the function system() to system2() solved it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I got that fix by installing RTools and adding RBuildTools to the path:

```
Sys.setenv("PATH" = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"),
    "C:\\RBuildTools\\3.4\\bin",
    "C:\\RBuildTools\\3.4\\mingw_32",
    "C:\\RBuildTools\\3.4\\mingw_64", sep = ";"))
```

I don't understand these things clearly but @cdeterman solutions was not working for building my package while its example `evalCpp("1 + 1")` did.